# Simple semaphore implementation with form application

Tags: c#, semaphore

I want to show an example application of semaphores for a specific problem for my homework.
I added 3 buttons to my C# form and I want to show that only one button at a specific time executes the bank account function in my code. When I click the three buttons in two seconds, the bank account function must run only one time. Because I have a Thread.Sleep(6000) for 6 seconds wait in bank account function. But three of my click runs by 6 second intervals consecutively. How can I change my code to run only one time when I press three buttons consecutively.
The Code is:

namespace semafor_form

{

```
public partial class Form1 : Form

   {
   Semaphore semafor=new Semaphore(1,1);

   delegate void SetTextCallback(string text);

   private void SetText(string text)
   {

       if (this.textBox2.InvokeRequired)
       {
           SetTextCallback d = new SetTextCallback(SetText);
           this.Invoke(d, new object[] { text });
       }
       else
       {
           this.textBox2.Text = text;
       }
   }

      public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void BankAccount()
    {
       semafor.WaitOne();
       double a = Convert.ToDouble (textBox1.Text) + Convert.ToDouble (textBox2.Text);
       Thread.Sleep(6000);
       semafor.Release(); 
       SetText(a.ToString());  
    }

    private void btnATM_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(BankAccount));
        t.Start();
     }

    private void btnCOUNTER_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(BankAccount));
        t.Start();
    }

    private void btnINT_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(BankAccount));
        t.Start();
    }
 }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I may have misread your question. You don't want the buttons to do anything when the thread is being used? (so you'll miss transactions?)

Try this:

```
private void BankAccount()
{
   if (semafor.WaitOne(0))
   {
       double a = Convert.ToDouble (textBox1.Text) + Convert.ToDouble (textBox2.Text);
       Thread.Sleep(6000);
       semafor.Release(); 
       SetText(a.ToString()); 
   } 
}
```

---

Try changing `Semaphore semafor=new Semaphore(1,1);` to `Semaphore semafor=new Semaphore(0,1);`

You are initializing a new semaphore without ever releasing it.

Comment: Thanks Jason, I have done what you said but now the bank account function never works. The bank account function must run once evenif I click multiple times  throughout the thread sleep time.

Comment: Changing to `new Semaphore(0, 1)` will make it so that no thread can acquire the semaphore.

Comment: I tried "Semaphore semafor=new Semaphore(1,1)"  with "if (semafor.WaitOne(0))" and it is OK. It works if semaphore start from 1.

Answer (score 0):

This really doesn't sound like an appropriate use of a semaphore. Your problem definition, if I'm reading it correctly, says that the three buttons are mutually exclusive: that pressing any one of them will render *all* of the buttons inactive for six seconds. You *can* use a semaphore for this, but a mutex would be more appropriate.

In any event, the problem you're experiencing is that you're waiting on the semaphore, so when the first transaction is done one of the other threads will acquire the semaphore and process. What you want to do is to *try* to acquire the semaphore. Here's an example.

An example of the latter:

```
private void BankAccount()
{
   if (semafor.WaitOne(0))  // tries to acquire the semaphore
   {
       double a = Convert.ToDouble (textBox1.Text) + Convert.ToDouble (textBox2.Text);
       Thread.Sleep(6000);
       semafor.Release(); 
       SetText(a.ToString());
   }
}
```

The `WaitOne(0)` says, "Try to acquire the semaphore. If it's not immediately available, then return false. If it is available, acquire it and return true."

You could also do this in the button handler. That is, have the button handler acquire the semaphore (using `WaitOne(0)`), and have it exit without starting the thread if it can't acquire the semaphore. If it does acquire the semaphore, start the thread and have the thread proc release the semaphore when done.